# Firebase Authentication - Open Sourcing Android App

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

**Is there a way for [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhKuIo_zV4wIVhRx9Ch1VwAh7EAAYASAAEgLRrvD_BwE) to work in an open sourced app without requiring an `SHA-1` key?**

I've open sourced the [Android code](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse) for [Coinverse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.coinverse), the first cryptocurrency news app for audiocasts on-the-go, in order to share Android best practices and architecture. The goal is for the developer to run the de-compiled app from Android Studio and login.

I've done the following for Firestore Database, Storage, YouTube API, and etc. to work as expected for developers downloading the project from GitHub:

- New *open source* Firebase project
- New API keys
- Firestore database [budget limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#manage_spending)
- Firestore Security [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) and [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start) rules

Comment: Open-sourcing the code is one thing, but it sounds like you also want all contributors to use the same Firebase project. Do I understand that correctly? This is quite unusual. It's much more common to have the contributors use their own Firebase project for their own development, and then use a non-shared Firebase project of your own for the releases. Would this not work for your use-case?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - There are two **non-shared** Firebase projects for _staging_ and _production_ used for the releases. There is a third **shared** project to provide data and features for the open sourced code. For the app to work there is a feed of shared data in Firestore, **.txt** files in Storage, and a Cloud Function to convert  **.txt** files to **.mp3**s. Your comment gave me the proposed hybrid approach below to create a **shared** project that provides access to the backend data and Cloud Functions, without exposing the backend code, and allows users to auth on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Shared and Private Firebase Instances

**Strategy** - Create both an *open source* **shared** Firebase instance to provide access to shared data and Cloud Functions, and have developers who download the GitHub project create their own **private** Firebase instance for authentication used as the default instance via the *google-services.json* file.

***Pro-tip* - Be sure to identify a unique `SHA-1` key with each Firebase project that requires it, otherwise there'll be an authentication error [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281788/firebaseuiexception-code-10-initializing-multiple-projects/57281818#57281818).**

### Shared Firebase Project

- Initialize the shared *open source* Firebase project with the [Use multiple projects in your application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application) programmatic implementation (separate project from the non-shared *staging* and *production* projects used for releases). - `FirebaseApp.getInstance("openSourceProject")` **Note**: `setProjectId(...)` also needs to be set for the `FirebaseOptions` although not mentioned in the link above and any other setters for services used such as Storage.
- Populate app with public content and price data from shared Firestore project - `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("openSourceProject"))`
- Use shared Cloud Functions and Firebase Storage to create **.mp3** files from Storage **.txt** files and access **.mp3s** from Storage. - `FirebaseStorage.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("openSourceProject"))` and `FirebaseFunctions.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("openSourceProject"))`

### User’s Private Firebase Project

- Initialized as default Firebase project instance via the *google-services.json* file.
- Use for authentication with their `SHA-1` key
- Save logged in user data to their Firestore instance - `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()`
- Create a Firebase token for [delete user functionality](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/tree/master/firestore/solution-deletes#setup)